# How can I store multiple values inside one localStorage key?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I store `localStorage` value without losing last value stored on it
I write code to insert row to table contient data from input everytime I click button 'insert new row' but I have issue after fill the table I want use table's data to insert to SQL database table using `localStorage` and ajax I do it but my problem he give me just data of last row because when I click save he give `localStorage` new value

```html
<!-- my problem : console.log shows me last item - I want to store all my inputs products without losing previous when I click button save -->

<input type="text" id="products">  
<button onclick="myfunction()">save</button>

<script>
  function myfunction() {
    var products = document.getElementbyid("products").value;
    var save_listProducts = localStorage.setItem("data",products);
  }

  var get_listProducts = localStorage.getItem("data");
  console.log(get_listProducts);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add little bit more code in order to maintain a "list" (array) in `localStorage`. There is no problem with actually storing an array in `localStorage` as long as it is a string - and to convert an array into a string ( and be able to parse it back later ) you can use JSON.stringify (and JSON.parse to get it back)

```js
function addNewItem (item) {
  let myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
  myList.push(item);
  localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(myList));
}

function getAllItems () {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
}
```

```js
function removeItem (index) {
  let myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
  myList.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(myList));
}
```

This is just an example and would need to be modified to fit your code, please do not just copy/paste it

### In your example

```
<input type="text" id="product">  
<button onclick="myfunction()">save</button>

<script>

  function myfunction() {
    var product = document.getElementbyid("product").value;
    addNewItem(product);
    console.log(getAllItems());
  }

  function addNewItem (item) {
    var myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
    myList.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(myList));
  }

  function getAllItems () {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Should i put this code inside onclick myfunction()  to display through console.log the output of                                                    
 let myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[ ]")); even when fill input and click save I will saving my old let mylist until the final time I clicked

Comment: I tried including your example to show how you can use it ! Updated my answer